# How to place a progress bar on each recycler view item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, progress-bar

i want to add a progress bar before loading of each recycler view item.I am able to add progress bar but when to make it visible and invisible??

Comment: You mean you want a progressbar that's always visible?

Answer (score 0):

'you can set its visivility as gone or visible in java class as bellow'

```
progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
```

'or'

```
progressBar.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: i know that but where to set them in the adapter view so that before loading of each recycler view item i can get a progress bar

Comment: if you are using volley or retrofit while json parsing of  your data store a bit for response in your model class and then make it true or false as your get response from server. Then in your onBindviewHolder() get that bit first and set a check if your response is true then set the progressbar visibility Gone and show your list item as above in answer

Comment: Try to set it visible in the `ViewHolder` constructor and set it to invisible in the `onBindViewHolder` method of the `RecycleView`

Comment: @shukiavraham already did that ...it doesnot show me progress bar this way